# How to control all combination subset against userinput using itertool in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write a code to get all combinations against 5 user input sets where each output subset only matches <= 3 elements from any of the input sets.

Example:

```
userInput1=(a,b,c,d,e)
userInput2=(c,d,e,f,g)
userInput3=(f,g,h,i,j)
userInput4=(g,h,i,j,k)
userInput5=(k,l,m,n,o)

  # Turn 5 lists into 1 large list with no duplicates
    allEntries = list(set(userInput1 + userInput2 + userInput3 + userInput4 + userInput5    ))

 # Generate all possible list combinations
    allCombinations = list(itertools.combinations( allEntries,5))
    print  "All combinations:"
    for subset in allCombinations:

        ?????????
        print subset
```

How do I do this check to limit the overlap?  For instance, (g,i,j,k,o) fails because it shares **4** elements with userInput4.

E.g. - all combination

```
(a,c,j,l,o)
(k,b,a,m,n)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't your first output be `a, b, c, f, g`, which would match three integers from the first `userInput`, and two or less from the others? `set`ifying would make the outputs less predictable admittedly, so to ensure the result I'm describing, you want to define `allEntries` with: `allEntries = sorted(set(userInput1 + userInput2 + userInput3 + userInput4 + userInput5))` so the outputs are predictably ordered.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to do that, after all when you create the "big list", information on origin is lost. You might have to manually check each combination whether they contain more than 3 from any of the input lists.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a simple solution with **itertools**.  However, you do have the correct start.  Now, check each list as you produce it:

```
check_set = [
    set(userinput1),    
    set(userinput2),    
    set(userinput3),    
    set(userinput4),    
    set(userinput5)
    ]
for five in itertools.combinations( allEntries,5):
    five_set = set(five)

    # If there are no overlaps of more than 3 elements,
    #    accept the solution.
    if !any(len(five_set.intersection(user_set)) > 3
            for user_set in check_set):
        print five
        #  ... or whatever you do to save the good combination.
```